# Does the ∞-category of Derived/Spectral schemes admit all colimits over constant diagrams?

Tags: homotopy-theory, derived-algebraic-geometry

In the case of ordinary schemes, all coproducts exist, so given any constant diagram $D_S:C\to \operatorname{Sch}$, the colimit over $D_S$ is isomorphic to the coproduct of $S$ over the connected components of $C$.  In the homotopical setting, colimits over constant diagrams are much more interesting, representing tensors by homotopy types.

Do all colimits over constant diagrams exist in the ∞-category of derived schemes or spectral schemes?  Where can I find a proof?

Comment: If you want interesting colimits, you should probably be taking them as derived stacks.

Comment: Yes, colimits of schemes will usually be stacks, except in special cases.  Here is what I believe is supposed to be true: Let $DM$ be the $\infty$-category of spectral Deligne-Mumford stacks.  Let $DM^{et}\subseteq DM$ be the non-full subcategory of al objects, but only etale morphisms.  Then (i) $DM^{et}$ has all small colimits, and (ii) $DM^{et}\to DM$ preserves such colimits.  Since identity maps are etale, this says that colimits of constant diagrams always exist.